# How to get View of dynamic fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

i created dynamic fragment and i want get View of fragment.
This my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragmenttext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Class of fragment:

```
package webviewtest.webviewtest;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
        return myFragmentView;
    }
}
```

and my activity layout with fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/myfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in "onCreate" method i try get "TextView" of fragment

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.myfragment, new MyFragment());
ft.commit();

TextView textFragment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fragmenttext);
textFragment.setText("Some text");
```

But i got "Null Pointer Exception", where is my mistake?

Comment: Try myFragmentView.findViewById in your fragment class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here: `ft.commit()`;

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html) of `commit()`:

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen
>   immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be
>   done the next time that thread is ready.

So just because you called `commit()`, doesn't mean that the fragment is inflated in the activity, i.e, `onCreateView()` need not be called immediately.

So how to handle this?

Well, you need to handle this via `Interface`. Create an interface and make your `Activity` implement it. Then in your `onActivityCreated()` method in your fragment call the method in your interface. Inside that method, you will do the `findViewById()` on the TextView. I have laid down the skeleton on how to implement this.

```
  public interface IFragmentListener{
       void fragmentInitialized();
  }
```

```
 public MainActivity extends Activity implements IFragmentListener{

      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            myFragment.setFragmentListener(this);
            ft.add(R.id.myfragment, myFragment);
            ft.commit();
      }

      public void fragmentInitialized(){
            TextView textFragment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fragmenttext);
            textFragment.setText("Some text");
      }
 }
```

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

     IFragmentListener listener;

     public void setFragmentListener(IFragmentListener listener){
            this.listener = listener;
     }

     public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            if(listener != null){
                  listener.fragmentInitialized();
            }
     }
}
```

Of course, you need to do all this, only if you want to access the `TextView` of your `Fragment` from your `Activity`. If you want to access if from you fragment, then just do the `findViewById()`, inside the `onActivityCreated()` method of your `Fragment`.